# How can I filter an array of objects with a value from another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to write a function which takes an array of objects with certain key value pairs as the first argument. And an object with key value pairs as the second argument.

The function should check if the key value pairs from the second argument are found in the array of objects from the first argument.

If so, it should return an array of objects which have the matching name and value pairs.

For example, if I have an array of objects (first argument):

```
[{name: "Peter", age: 21}, {name: "Kate", age: 18}, {name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}]
```

And as the second argument:

```
{age: 17}
```

It should return:

```
[{name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}]
```

Because of the matching value `age`

This is what I have come up with but don't know what to put in the `for...in` loop:

```
   function checkTheName(list, check) {
     let newArr = [];
     for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
        for(let key in list[i]){
            // Stuck here
        }
     }
     return newArr;
   }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to filter object array based on attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722159/javascript-how-to-filter-object-array-based-on-attributes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `filter` and `every` methods.

```js
let a = [{name: "Peter", age: 21}, {name: "Kate", age: 18}, {name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}]
let b = {age: 17}

function checkTheName(list, check) {
  return list.filter(o => Object.keys(check).every(k => {
    return (k in o) && check[k] == o[k]
  }))
}

console.log(checkTheName(a, b))
```

Comment: Note that this answer, unlike others, doesn't assume any key values and will work for any second argument

Comment: `k in o` would be better than checking `o[k]` for a truthy value, especially in the event that `0` or an empty string is a possible value.

Answer (score 1):

A simple ES6 version with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const data = [{name: "Peter", age: 21}, {name: "Kate", age: 18}, {name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}];

const fObj = {age: 17};

const filtred = data.filter(item =>
    Object.keys(fObj).every(k => item.hasOwnProperty(k) && item[k] === fObj[k])
);

console.log(filtred);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the array and test for that property:

```
function checkTheName(check, list){
    for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
        }
    }
}

var array =[{name: "Peter", age: 21}, {name: "Kate", age: 18}, {name: "Tihon", 
age: 17}, {namenter code heree: "Poopy", age: 17}]
;

var resultObject = checkTheName( array,"string 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filter to loop over the array.

```
function findByAge(myArr, obj){
    myArr.filter( (item) => {
       if(obj.age === item.age){
         return item
       }
    })
}
```

This will return an array with just the array items that you are looking for.

You can call it following line. Since the function returns a new array. We need to give the new array a name (newArray in this example).

`var newArray = findByAge(myArr, obj)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an if condition comparing the `age` value of your `check` object with the `age` value of the `list` object. In case, both the values are equal, push object in `newArr`.

```js
let list = [{ name: "Peter", age: 21 }, { name: "Kate", age: 18 }, { name: "Tihon", age: 17 }, { name: "Poopy", age: 17 }], 
    check = { age: 17 };
function checkTheName(list, check) {
  let newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].age == check.age) {
      newArr.push(list[i]);
    }
  }
  return newArr;
}
console.log(checkTheName(list, check));
```

Alternatively, you can also use `array#filter`.

```js
let list = [{name: "Peter", age: 21}, {name: "Kate", age: 18}, {name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}],
    check = {age: 17},
    result = list.filter(o => o.age === check.age);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filterobj ={age:17};
var data=[{name: "Tihon", age: 17}, {name: "Poopy", age: 17}]
 var newArray = data.filter(function (el) {
 return el.age ==filterobj.age;
}
```